# Get Current DateTime C# without hour

Tags: c#, timepicker, timespan, datetimeoffset

Hi I currently have a TimePicker. It returns an object TimeSpan.
What I need to do is to set a DateTimeOffset that is equal to current date plus the TimeSpan from the TimePicker.

How can I actually get the current DateTimeOffset.now that doesn't have a Time on it, only the Date so that I can add the offset to it.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Guys. I must have forgotten the DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.

Comment: Yes but don't forget you'll get a DateTime instead of a DateTimeOffset (see answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in `DateTime` object you have a `Date` property, it returns date part without time (it means time is 00:00:00).

```
DateTime today = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date;
DateTime result = today + yourTimeSpan;
```

With this solution will lost `Offset` information (because `Date` is a `DateTime`). To keep it you just need to subtract time part:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset result = now - now.Time + yourTimeSpan;
```

Or with constructor:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset result = new DateTimeOffset(now.Date + yourTimeSpan, now.Offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just `.Date` it?

```
var a = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
DateTime.Today
```

instead of Now.

Comment: I suppose he is using DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime because he needs Offset part (time zone).